# Post directly to own wall

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

In my iOS app, I want to post on own fb wall directly. I don't want to show the fb dialog but rather I'll just supply programmatically the required parameters..but how? Tnx

Comment: got it.

     NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"how are you?", @"message",nil];
    
    [_sharedFbInstance.facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];

Comment: Great, exactly what I was looking for...

Answer (score 0):

Try the ios api.  http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/